# Completness of strong operator topology on norm-bounded sets

Tags: gn.general-topology, operator-theory, limits-and-convergence

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and $B(H)$ the space of bounded linear operators on $H$. It is know, that the strong operator topology is metrizable on norm-bounded sets of $B(H)$. My question is, if the strong operator topology is even complete on norm-bounded sets of $B(H)$? Are there maybe any other restrictions to the underlying space $H$? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow! Three remarks: (i) Please note that completeness is a property of the metric, not of the topology, so the question can only be asked for a specific choice of the metric (or would you like to know whether there *exists* a complete metric that induces the topology)? (ii) In general, the answer will depend on the set you consider. Are you interested in closed sets only? (iii) Imposing "other restrictions on the underlying space $H$" doesn't make much sense since there is - up to isomorphism - only one infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space.

Comment: @JochenGlueck: Thanks for your comments. I agree, that up to isomorphism there is only one separable Hilbert space. I want to have a look at the closed unit ball (and there multiples) in $B(H)$. Does this help?

Comment: Thank you for your response! This resolves my remarks (ii) and (iii). What is still open is remark (i): are you interested in completeness of a specific metric on the closed unit ball that induces the strong operator topology, or would you merely like to know whether there *exists* a complete metric on the closed unit ball that induces the strong operator topology?

Comment: @JochenGlueck: The question is simply if the strong operator topology is a complete locally convex topology on the closed balls of $B(H)$. Maybe my comment regarding the metrizability is a little bit confusing. Sorry for that.

Comment: Alright, I see your point now. Thank you for the clarification! It seems that the answer is "yes" (no matter whether the Hilbert space $H$ is separable or not): If $(T_\alpha)$ is a net in the closed unit ball of $B(H)$ which is Cauchy with respect to the strong operator topology, then for each $x \in H$, the net $(T_\alpha x)$ is Cauchy in $H$ and thus converges to a vector $Tx$ of norm at most $\|x\|$. Hence, $T$ is a bounded linear operator on $H$ of norm at most $1$ and $T_\alpha$ converges strongly to $T$. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @JochenGlueck: Thanks a lot for your answer, this indeed answers my question. Hence, this also works for general Banach spaces instead of Hilbert spaces?

Comment: Yes, indeed - it is true for general Banach spaces, too.